# Set default values for model using Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've added Entity Framework to an existing project with existing tables. These tables contains a couple of uniqueidentifier columns that is NULL. When I load data from these my model-property is also null and not Guid.Empty. I've tried setting the default value using both the constructor and

```
AlterColumn("tblItems", "ThreadRoot", c => c.Guid(nullable: true, defaultValue: Guid.Empty));
```

but it still return null.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have the permission to change the existing database structure?

Comment: are you using a code first approach?

Comment: yes, I am using a code first approach

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but why do you need guid.empty instead of null? Guid.Empty and null do not refer to same thing. A nullable guid may have either null or guid.empty as its value.

Comment: there is an existing codebase that does Guid.Empty checks and not null checks... So instead of changing the codebase I was hoping I could set a default value. Not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I load data from these my model-property is also null and not Guid.Empty

That's because the data already present will contain `null`, because they were stored before you issued the `AlterColumn` method. The default  value will be written when a new record is inserted, when the appropriate column is not set.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, just add the default value to the property:

```
public class Item {
    public Guid ThreadRoot { get; set; }

    public Item() {
        ThreadRoot = Guid.Empty; //default value
    }
 }
```